# Running Lando on PC for Drupal Environment Composer errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, composer-php, lando

I'm stuck trying to install a Drupal Environment on Lando using a PC under WSL. When running composer install, I get the following errors listed below.

Does anyone have experience with these errors as it's preventing me from running lando.

Errors:

I'm stuck trying to install a Drupal Environment on Lando using a PC under WSL. When running composer install, I get the following errors listed below.

Does anyone have experience with these errors as it's preventing me from running lando.

Errors:

```
> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-curl * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's curl extension.
  Problem 2
    - alchemy/zippy is locked to version 0.4.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - alchemy/zippy 0.4.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.
  Problem 3
    - composer/installers is locked to version v1.6.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - composer/installers v1.6.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 4
    - cweagans/composer-patches is locked to version 1.6.5 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - cweagans/composer-patches 1.6.5 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 5
    - drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold is locked to version 2.6.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold 2.6.1 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 6
    - drupal/coder is locked to version 8.3.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - drupal/coder 8.3.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.
  Problem 7
    - drupal/console-extend-plugin is locked to version 0.9.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - drupal/console-extend-plugin 0.9.2 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 8
    - easyrdf/easyrdf is locked to version 0.9.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.
  Problem 9
    - instaclick/php-webdriver is locked to version 1.4.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - instaclick/php-webdriver 1.4.6 requires ext-curl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's curl extension.
  Problem 10
    - league/csv is locked to version 8.2.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - league/csv 8.2.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.
  Problem 11
    - oomphinc/composer-installers-extender is locked to version v1.1.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - oomphinc/composer-installers-extender v1.1.2 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 12
    - phpunit/phpunit is locked to version 6.5.14 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.14 requires ext-mbstring * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.
  Problem 13
    - alchemy/zippy 0.4.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.
    - drupal/console 1.8.0 requires alchemy/zippy 0.4.3 -> satisfiable by alchemy/zippy[0.4.3].
    - drupal/console is locked to version 1.8.0 and an update of this package was not requested.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Does anyone have experience with these errors?

Comment: Is there anything unclear about that error message? It asks you to install the cURL extension, among others

Comment: Actually I was able to get past most of them. Composer threw me errors because it was on a newer version. I rolled this back and it seems to be running fine now.